# Gradle build stuck at "Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry."

Tags: java, gradle, build, fortify, jstack

I'm currently using HP Fortify tool to scan for security vulnerabilities in a project. At the time of scanning Fortify's CLI allows build tools to integrate into its CLI commands so as to build and simultaneously scan the files present in the project. I'm using the below command:

`sourceanalyzer -b mcapbookvalue -gradle -verbose ./gradlew -x test --console=verbose -debug --continue assemble`

But the build is getting stuck at:

```
2020-01-14T12:31:39.836-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.[0K
2020-01-14T12:31:39.836-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-01-14T12:31:39.836-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2020-01-14T12:31:39.836-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2020-01-14T12:31:39.836-0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

The build is successful if I'm building the project without using Fortify's command integrated, only with:

`./gradlew -x test --console=verbose -debug --continue assemble`

I'm not able to figure out why the gradle build is getting stuck. And reading and understanding what is happening in the thread dump log is beyond me.

Thread dump(jstack log): https://drive.google.com/file/d/13b6vdDGCWoke7McM_FJROVOkvTaRGqem/view?usp=sharing

It would be great if any help is received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another tidbit I discovered is the gradle build integrated with Fortify runs successfully on a windows machine but not on a linux machine.

Comment: Same issue using the `nebula.rpm` plugin.

Comment: Do you by any chance have `GRADLE_HOME` directory on nfs?

Comment: Didn't get what you meant by nfs. But I did add the GRADLE_HOME to the path variable in Win 10 and my linux box.

Comment: any chance you have lower memory and cpu configuration at your linux machine than your windows one?
you can check cpu usage and memory usage on linux machine if there is any contention.

Comment: Simplify your run by disabling gradle daemon as well as caching. Does --no-daemon and --no-build-cache options make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

So the thread dump is really a tool for the developer(s) to look at.  Users (even other software developers like you and me) wouldn't be able to really debug the issue from it without knowing the code base. It's good that you included it so if a more knowledgeable person comes along they could give us some insight.

That being said if you've used the thread dump before in your own projects you can begin to see what might be happening.  Again I'm not a gradle dev so take this with a grain of salt.  But essentially we're really only interested in threads with a state of `WAITING (on object monitor)`.  And there are only 4 of those.  `Finalizer`, `Common Cleaner`, `Daemon #20` and an Execution Worker.  `Finalizer` and `Common Cleaner` aren't doing any work so they can be ignored.  The `Daemon #20` seems to be a gradle daemon thread that kicked off the gradle script so it's just waiting for the script to finish which is expected.  So that leaves the Execution Worker which looks like this:

```
"Execution worker for ':'" #42 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=2818.31ms elapsed=196.05s tid=0x00007f9358702800 nid=0x16cfe in Object.wait()  [0x00007f93428f1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.5/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000ea1d41f8> (a java.lang.ProcessImpl)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.5/Object.java:328)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(java.base@11.0.5/ProcessImpl.java:495)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000ea1d41f8> (a java.lang.ProcessImpl)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@11.0.5/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.5/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.5/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@11.0.5/Method.java:566)
```

The interesting part is `java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor` so it appears that gradle is just waiting for an external process to finish.  This doesn't appear to be a deadlock situation or any exotic locking issue which is good news.  Basically the HP tool is just running and not finishing.  And suddenly `halting problem` becomes all too real.  Is it going to finish or is it hung?  We can't know.

But what I'd do is look at the `top` output on Linux, and find the process that gradle kicked off (ie the HP process).  Is the CPU usage bouncing around for that process?  Then maybe it's just doing stuff that takes a while, be patient, let it run, and see if it finishes.  If it's not running then you got a bigger problem.  I bet that on Linux the HPI software is trying to scan something that it shouldn't, and maybe this a config issue or difference between Linux vs Windows.  Total speculation, but just my gut feel on this.

What my next move might be would be to see if I can manually run the tool on Linux outside of gradle.  What we found from the dump is that gradle doesn't seem to be contributing to the issue so let's isolate the HP tool and see if we can get more error messages or something from it.  Some things to consider:

- Is gradle giving it enough memory to run?  If the executable you run manually is different than Gradle's it could be a difference in configuration in Linux vs Windows possibly.
- Is there a gradle plugin for the HP tool involved and is there some config option you need to configure on Linux?
- Is there enough available memory for the HP tool AND gradle to run on the Linux box?  Maybe your linux boxes upper memory limit is different than your Windows box.  If you can spin up a bigger box maybe that'll fix Linux.

I don't have a complete answer today for you so just a strategy for you to figure this one out.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .gradle directory in project folder & re-running the gradle task resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle supports parallel execution of tasks, and this might sometimes cause issues. You can try disabling parallel execution:

```
./gradlew -x test --console=verbose -debug --continue assemble --no-parallel
```